# Discern between physical key stroke and repeated key

Tags: autohotkey

In Autohotkey: is there a way to discern between a physical key stroke and a repeated key?

I am looking for the equililant to [KeyEventArgs.IsRepeat](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.isrepeat?view=netframework-4.7.2) in dot net.

I hope to find something better like this:

```
*key1::
If (hotkey1_active)
   return
hotkey1_active := 1
Myfunction1()
return

*key1 up::
hotkey1_active := 0
return
```

Above sample code was found [here](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/59154-ignoring-key-repeat-in-hotkeys/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to know, the only thing known is that repetitions consist of key downs without a key ups.

Maybe there's some way to not having to create a variable for each hotkey.

Try this, I think it could be good enough for normal circumstances:

```
*a::
    if (A_PriorHotkey = A_ThisHotKey)
        return
    Myfunction1()
return

*a Up:: return ; Does nothing but change A_PriorHotkey.
```

Comment: Still not exactly what I was hoping for, but at least your solution does not need an additional variable

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no built-in syntax for keydown check. But you can check the state with [getkeystate](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm) in a loop:

```
key := "a"
state0 := getkeystate(key, "P")                 ; init key state
c := 0

loop 
{
    sleep 30                                    ; sleep to reduce CPU usage
    state1 := getkeystate(key, "P")             ; getkeystate
    state_on := (state1 > state0)               ; check if key state is changed to 'on'
    ; state_off := (state1 < state0)                ; check if key state is changed to 'off'
    state0 := state1                            ; save previous state
    if (state_on) {
        c += 1
        tooltip %key% pressed %c% times
        ; Myfunction1()
    }
}
```

With very high probability this will be the physical state change.

Comment: getkeystate is always returning true. The scenario is, that I press a key and hold it for lets say 5 seconds. During that 5 secs I receive hundres of identical hotkeys that I like to detect (and ignore).

Comment: @sam if you need to do something with repeated events as well, then of course this is not what you want. Some variant of your initial code should do the job.